# Failed to sync remote state, coordinate update error: No cluster leader

Tags: consul

I have a cluster of 3 consul servers and 2 consul clients. 
'consul members' displays that all the nodes have joined. Am getting an error "Failed to sync remote state, coordinate update error: No cluster leader". I have verified peers.json file, it has list of servers along with the port.

Can someone let me know why number of peers is showing as 0 and state as 'Follower' in all 3 consul servers when I execute 'consul info' ?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this issue occurring for multiple people several times.

If on k8s besides setting `-bootstrap-expect` to the number of servers you're running (e.g. 3-5 pods), deleting all PVCs and volumes after uninstalling consul completely was the only solution that worked for me.

It didn't matter what was done and re/uninstalls (helm based) Consul would be unable to properly bootstrap and elect a leader until not only all components were removed from the (k8s) cluster but the PVCs and volumes.